# mysql : Is it possible to ignore some tables in cold backup?

Tags: mysql, backup

We take every day the backup of a folder from production to uat with rsync.

That folder, among others, contains the physical files of a mysql database.

Is it possible to exclude some tables during the backup process?

Edit: If yes, which files should I exclude in the mysql directory?

Thank you!

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. The DBA sister site of SO offers help in questions regarding operating a database server.

Answer (score 0):

use --exclude='pattern' where pattern can be file or directory eg '/dir/file*'
there is another option too, ie   --exclude-from

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know specifically which files should I exclude? Namely, a mysql table to which files in the mysql directory correspond to?

Comment: Sorry, didnt realize you were trying to ignore tables. 
   Best bet would be mysqldump with --ignore-table option. I wont advise physical copy in this case since it may mess up dictionary entries.